# How do you make plotting two pandas Series in the same ipython notebook cell use different colors automatically?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

When I run this in one cell, both plot lines are blue.  I could have sworn I saw Wes do a demo of baby names with two plots where the two plot lines came out in different colors without having to specify a color:

```
pd.Series(randn(100)).cumsum().plot()
pd.Series(randn(100)).cumsum().plot()
```

Yes, it was at 2:06:44 of this YouTube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w26x-z-BdWQ

Comment: I'm sure this *used* to be the behaviour...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass a couple of kwargs to the call to `plot`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2)).cumsum().plot(ax=ax)
```

Comment: He asked specifically "without specifying a color".

Comment: Oh. My bad. Just stuff them into a dataframe per my edited response.

Comment: Both K.-Michael Aye's and Paul H's answers gave the desired results so it was hard to choose which one to mark as the answer.  Ultimately, I'd like to see pandas do this automatically.  I went with Paul H's answer because it used pandas to solve the problem as opposed to having to pass two members of a data frame to another function.  I know that might be a poor reason for picking one solution over another...  Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how Wes did it in the video, but when using plot(df.index, df.column) and do that several times with different columns, then the graphs have different colors.

(I'm using the plot command from ipython --pylab) for this. )